# Why I have to surround with try/cacth

Tags: java, try-catch

I have method

```
private void writeObject(ObjectOutputStream oos) throws IOException
```

In body I write keySet of some HashMap

```
        for(E e : map.keySet()) {
        oos.writeObject(e);
    }
```

And it's look OK
But if I want to replase this code on

```
map.forEach((k, v) -> oos.writeObject(k));
```

I have to surround it with try/catch. Like this

```
        map.forEach((k, v) -> {
        try {
            oos.writeObject(k);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    });
```

And I can't understand for what

**Update** I can't understand why I need to processed exception in method body if I anounce in method title that I want it to throw away.

Comment: Are you saying that when you use ` for(E e : map.keySet()) {
        oos.writeObject(e);
    }` you dont have to use `try catch` but when replace code you have to use `try catch` ?

Comment: Yes. Sorry fo my English

Answer (score 0):

The **try** block will execute a sensitive code which can throw exceptions
The **catch** block will be used whenever an exception (of the type caught) is thrown in the try block

The **throws** keyword in the method prototype is used to specify that your method might throw exceptions of the specified type. It's useful when you have checked exception (exception that you have to handle) that you don't want to catch in your current method.

Answer (score 0):

That is because forEach() takes Consumer as argument. And Consumer isn't declared throws any checked exception. So your lambda should also be Consumer and do not throw any checked exceptions. So any checked exception should be caught in you lambda body.

Comment: thank you. I will go to read more about lambda